# Found duplicate file for APK: lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver

Tags: android, java-native-interface, gdbserver

I have two jni projects on android. I want to use one of them for developing the project. One of the projects calls a method of the other project. I don't get any error while compiling the program. However, when I try to run the program I get this error:

```
Origin 1: /home/devuser/Desktop/workspaceJava/arTTClientDeveloperProject/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
Origin 2: /home/devuser/Desktop/workspaceJava/ARTTClientMobileAPI/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[2012-08-07 16:10:49 - arTTClientDeveloperProject] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
```

Do you have any ideas about this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this problem because I had NDK_DEBUG=1 defined in building both of the libraries. This should only be at the top level I think.

Comment: Either NDK_DEBUG is duplicated or android:debuggable="true" in both  manifests.

Answer (score 0):

You have added .jar in 2 place in your project. In libs folder and added using "add external jar". Remove one.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in Gradle

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude "lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver"
}
```